# Check array values in object, if has key, then push a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to achieve that, fruits is checked in onTruck to find the existing keys, then push to a new array. Since they are different length, I am stuck on how to loop them.

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

var onTruck = {
    'apple': 100,
    'orange': 200,
    'banana': 500,
    'pineapple': 5,
    'mango': 'empty'
    }

let arr = []

Object.keys(onTruck).forEach((e, i) => {
  console.log(e === fruit[]) <- Need to loop fruit  
  arr.push[...]
})

// OUTPUT: 
arr = [['apple', '100'],['orange', '200'], ['banana', '500'] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method to generate a new array based on the key element array.

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

var onTruck = {
  'apple': 100,
  'orange': 200,
  'banana': 500,
  'pineapple': 5,
  'mango': 'empty'
}


var arr = fruits.map(v => [v, onTruck[v]]);

// in case some fields may miss in onTruck then add an additional filter
var arr1 = fruits.filter(v => v in onTruck).map(v => [v, onTruck[v]]);
// or with reduce
var arr2 = fruits.reduce((a, v) => v in onTruck ? [...a, [v, onTruck[v]]] : a, []);


console.log(arr)
console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

---

**FYI :** If you want to ignore properties which is not number or value is `empty` then use an additional filter condition(or filter).

For avoiding non digit values : `!isNaN(onTruck[v])`

For avoiding property with value `'empty'` : `onTruck[v] !== 'empty'`

*For eg:*

```
var arr = fruits.filter(v => v in onTruck && !isNaN(onTruck[v])).map(v => [v, onTruck[v]]);
```

Comment: mango will also be a part of your array, which should not be.

Comment: var arr2 = fruits.reduce((a, v) => v in onTruck && !isNaN(onTruck[v]) ? [...a, [v, onTruck[v]]] : a, []);

Comment: @TAB :  it's completely worked based on `var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`

Comment: Add mango in fruits. It will add empty fruit in resultant array.

Comment: @TAB : that's right mate, but we don't know the expected result... anyways I'd added it as side note in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code by using `Array.filter` and `Array.map`:

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
var onTruck = {
    'apple': 100,
    'orange': 200,
    'banana': 500,
    'pineapple': 5,
    'mango': 'empty'
}
const result = Object.keys(onTruck)
                     .filter((fruit) => fruits.includes(fruit))
                     .map((fruit) => [fruit, onTruck[fruit]]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = fruits.filter(function(fruit) {
  return fruit in onTruck;
}).map(function(fruit) {
  return [fruit, onTruck[fruit]]
});
```

Should work. Basically, I am filtering fruits existing in `onTruck` and then constructing the required array through the map function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

var onTruck = {
    'apple': 100,
    'orange': 200,
    'banana': 500,
    'pineapple': 5,
        'mango': 'empty'
    }

let arr = fruits.reduce((arr,b) => {
    if (!isNaN(onTruck[b])){
        arr.push([b, onTruck[b]]);
        return arr;
    } else return arr;

    },[])



console.log(arr)
```